# Receiving memory warning while dismissing UIImagePickerController in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, memory-warning

I´m working with a simple `UISplitViewController`. In my primary view (master) I have an option to take a photo from the camera using `UIImagePickerController` when user finish taking the photo or hits cancel I received a memory warning from the console. Does anyone has an idea of why this is happening?

Here is how I present the controller:

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
   cameraService = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];     
   cameraService.delegate    = self;
   cameraService.sourceType  = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

   [self presentViewController:cameraService animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

And here is how I dismiss the image picker view:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage * image
        = (UIImage *)[info valueForKeyPath:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Thanks!